# How can I redirect users on the new 404 page without plugin?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a 404 page in my theme but I am not using that page. I have created a new 404 page in WordPress using wpbakery page builder. I need to know how can I redirect users on the new 404 page without a plugin?

Comment: Do you want to redirect something like this https://www.example.com/404

Comment: @Bhautik, Yes, I have to redirect when user enter anything wrong

Comment: I tried in htaccess #ErrorDocument 404 https://mydomain.co/404 but it's not working

Comment: You can try this WordPress function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

Comment: @Bhautik, Yes, I am little bit confused how to use that code in the function.php

Comment: check my below answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use plugin [404page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404page/).

Or some code [adapted from this plugin](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/404page/trunk/inc/class-404page.php#L292):

```php
add_filter(
    '404_template',
    static function () {
        global $wp_query;

        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query('page_id='.$pageID);
        $wp_query->the_post();
        $template = get_page_template();
        rewind_posts();

        add_filter(
            'body_class',
            static function ($classes) {
                if (!in_array('error404', $classes, true)) {
                    $classes[] = 'error404';
                }

                return $classes;
            }
        );

        return $template;
    },
    999
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Crate 404page in the admin.
2. create a custom page template for that page.
3. add your custom 404 content
4. open 404.php file in your theme.
5. add this below code at the top of that file.

   ```
   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");

   header("Location: ".home_url('/404page/'));

   exit();
   ```
6. try to find something that not found and you will be redirected to your custom 404 page

also, you can try this action hooks for redirect to custom 404 page. put this code in your function.php file. this is the replace option of above point number 5)

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redreict_to_custom_404_page' );
function redreict_to_custom_404_page(){
    // check if is a 404 error
    if( is_404()  ){
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/404page/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Or if you want to create 404 page with WP bakery

1. Create a private 404page and build with WP bakery in the admin.
2. open 404.php file and get content of 404page by code below

   ```
    $page_id = 123; // 404page id
    $page    = get_post( $page_id );
    $content = $page->post_content;
    echo $content;
   ```

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Redirecting to a 404 page is bad, don’t do that. Any search engine bots etc. won’t get a proper 404 status code for the originally requested URL any more.

Comment: @CBroe, I have a different design for 404 pages so I create a page in the admin panel and build the page using wpbakery. I have to redirect my new 404 page.

Comment: Then you should somehow do that using whatever mechanism WP provides for this, but _not_ with an external redirect.

Comment: @NarenVerma check my edits. this will not affect your wp 404 mechanism.